# Hosting an ASP.Net web service

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio-2008

I have no idea how a webservice can be hosted in a web hosting. I couldnt find any explanation of this step by step. I tried many things to do this.

I created the web service in Visual Studio 2008 and I managed to use it in local. I could add web reference to my application in local. But when I uploaded the web service to my host, I can not use it. I uploaded it to both php and windows servers but it is not working on there.

is there any way ( of course there is ) to do this. Any link to explain how to do this ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check this link for some help http://www.windows-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/3249-how-can-i-install-a-web-service/

Comment: Given that you uploaded your ASP.NET Webservice to a  PHP Server tells  me that you're issues maybe start earlier... I would learn the basics first. OR try out Azure. There are good step by step tutorials around.